# send fields in a email

Tags: 7, entities, emails

I'm fairly new to D7 and I don't know where to start. I have a "Event" CT(ContentType) with many fields in it. Dates, prices, text, html description.

I need to put some fields in a plaintext email and send it to a specific adress. Thats the data export for a ticket system. Some of these fields need to be reformatted. Date => Timestamp, MD5 Hash etc. Textblob with HTML Tags => plaintext, etc.

Also it needs to be saved. So the User can see if its already submitted.

I'm a bit overwhelmed where to start. I think a module and drupal_mail() is the right way to start. How would you do it (General direction)?

Thx in advance
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Email Example in the [Examples Project](http://drupal.org/project/examples) should be just the thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the email to be a triggered event (like upon saving a node) you could create a Rule - http://drupal.org/project/rules

it is a bit unclear whether you want the email saved, or the node..